# Why is my print statement repeating twice?

Tags: python, csv

This is the loop I'm having a problem with, and I'm using the same CSV file I've used in my other questions:

I'm analyzing a 60MB CSV file about complaint IDs, and their complaints against certain companies. I ask the user for what date he/she wants to study, and when he/she enters a date, my program is supposed to produce a SINGLE line of code that has the corresponding list of IDs.

Basically, the `input_IDs` is a list of ID numbers, and `input_dates` is a list of Dates (in Month/Day/Year format) correlating to each ID.

```
matching_list = []


Date_Input = input("First, input a date in this format, 'Month/Day/Year.' ->       Type in 'Quit' if you are done. : ")

if Date_Input == "Quit":
    print ("Too bad you quit so early!")

for i in range(len(input_dates)):
    if input_dates[i] == Date_Input:
        matching_list.append(input_IDs[i])

if len(matching_list) > 0:
    print ("Here is the list of complaint IDs you can choose from and ask about :", matching_list)

while True:
    new_match_list = []

    if len(matching_list) == 0:
    Date_Input = input ("There are no complaint IDs available for that date! Enter another date: ")

    for x in range(len(input_dates)):
        if input_dates[x] == Date_Input:
           new_match_list.append(input_IDs[x])

    if len(new_match_list)>0:
        print ("Here is the list of complaint IDs you can choose from and ask about :", new_match_list)
        break
```

The code produces the aforementioned list of IDs correctly, but produces two copies, instead of just one:  Let's say I wanted a list of IDs that happened on
4/23/2015,

```
First, input a date in this format, 'Month/Day/Year.' -> Type in 'Quit' if you are done. : 4/23/2015
Here is the list of complaint IDs you can choose from and ask about : ['1344139', '1344055', '1343332', '1343188', '1343131', '1341190', '1340441', '1338003', '1336832', '1329966', '1301958', '1251144']
Here is the list of complaint IDs you can choose from and ask about : ['1344139', '1344055', '1343332', '1343188', '1343131', '1341190', '1340441', '1338003', '1336832', '1329966', '1301958', '1251144']
```

Why are there two print statements being produced, and not just one?

Comment: because you have two `"Here is . . . "` statements in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two print statements - one before the loop and one at its end. You can solve this by **removing** the printing block before the `while` and just putting it in the beginning of the loop:

```
while True:
    if len(new_match_list)>0:
        print ("Here is the list of complaint IDs you can choose from and ask about :", new_match_list)
        break

    new_match_list = []

    if len(matching_list) == 0:
    Date_Input = input ("There are no complaint IDs available for that date! Enter another date: ")

    for x in range(len(input_dates)):
        if input_dates[x] == Date_Input:
           new_match_list.append(input_IDs[x])
```